# Swapping adjacent rows in excels

Tags: excel

How do you sawp adjacent rows in excel.
In the attachment below, "col" is my data. How do I sawp adjacent rows, so that I get the data in "result" column.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `OFFSET()` and `MOD()` combinedly. Try-

```
=OFFSET(A2,(2*-MOD(ROW(),2))+1,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a non-volatile formula, independent of the location of the initial range (or where you want your resuts), you can try:

```
=INDEX(myRng,2*MOD(ROWS($1:1),2)-1+ROWS($1:1))
```

[image]